# Appending to an extracted file

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a procedure that is extracting data from the EDW to a file for another user in Business Objects to use.

I use a cursor to select the data that I need and then run it in a for loop as follows:

```
FOR x IN c_body LOOP

utl_file.put_line(out_file, x.data_line);
END LOOP;

  utl_file.fclose(out_file);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('copy file from ' ||lv_path||'/'||lv_filename|| ' to '                               ||lv_pub_path||'/'||lv_filename);
  OSUTIL.RUNOSCMD('cp -f '||lv_path||'/'||lv_filename||' '||lv_pub_path, lv_os_out, ln_os_num);

  IF ln_os_num != 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('copy file '||lv_filename||' failed. error = ' || lv_os_out || ' ' || ln_os_num);
    RAISE exit_now;
  END IF;
```

Is there a way that I can run the procedure multiple times and just append to the extracted file?
I am currently running a massive extract of 2 years history data and would rather append multiple times with smaller sets rather than use the full 24 months (it's going to take forever).

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Do you mean the file you're writing to with `utl_file`, or the target file you're copying that too in the OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append to a file using `UTL_FILE` with the append open mode of [`fopen`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70919):

> `open_mode`: Specifies how the file is opened. Modes include:
>
> - r -- read text
> - w -- write text
> - **a -- append text**
> - rb -- read byte mode
> - wb -- write byte mode
> - ab -- append byte mode

In your case you could also write to 24 (different) files so that you can run multiple procedures simultaneously, then merge the result files.

Answer (score 1):

You can [open the file in append mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#i1003526) instead of write mode:

```
out_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR', lv_filename, 'a');
```

If you want to create a new file each time but append to the target file you're copying to then you can do that at OS leve:

```
OSUTIL.RUNOSCMD('cat '||lv_path||'/'||lv_filename||' >> '||lv_pub_path,
  lv_os_out, ln_os_num);
```

Either way you'd need to make sure you have no file or an empty file before the start of the first of the multiple runs, or if you have to restart the whole thing. How much of an issue that is depends how you're deciding when to splitt he runs and how the file is named, etc.